# Docker container exits (code 255) with error "task already exists" and does not restart automatically

Tags: docker, containers, exit-code

I have a basic container that opens up a `ssh` tunnel to a machine.

Recently I noticed the container has exited with error code `255` with an error message saying the `task already exists`:

```
        "Id": "7eb92418992a1a1c3e44d6b47257dc503d4fa4d0f26050956533d617ac369479",
        "Created": "2022-08-29T18:19:41.286843867Z",
        "Path": "sh",
        "Args": [
            "-c",
            "apk update && apk add openssh-client &&\n       chmod 400 ~/.ssh/abc.pem\n       while true; do \n       exec ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -i ~/.ssh/abc.pem -nNT -L *:33333:localhost:5001 abc@192.168.1.1; \n       done"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "exited",
            "Running": false,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 0,
            "ExitCode": 255,
            "Error": "task 7eb92418992a1a1c3e44d6b47257dc503d4fa4d0f26050956533d617ac369479: already exists",
            "StartedAt": "2022-08-30T19:43:58.575463029Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2022-08-30T19:51:23.511624168Z"
        },
```

More importantly even though the restart policy is `always`, the docker engine did not start the container after the container exit.

```
  abc:
    container_name: abc
    image: alpine:latest
    restart: always
    command: > 
      sh -c "apk update && apk add openssh-client &&
             chmod 400 ~/.ssh/${PEM_FILENAME}
             while true; do 
             exec ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -i ~/.ssh/${PEM_FILENAME} -nNT -L *:33333:localhost:5001 abc@${IP}; 
             done"
    volumes:
      - ./ssh:/root/.ssh:rw
    expose:
      - 33333
```

- Does anyone know under what situation error `task already exists` can happen?
- Also any idea why docker engine did not start the container after exit?

**Update 1:**

- Also any idea why docker engine did not start the container after exit? *[Answered by @Mihai]*
  According to [Restart policy details](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#restart-policy-details):

> A restart policy only takes effect after a container starts
> successfully. In this case, starting successfully means that the
> container is up for at least 10 seconds and Docker has started
> monitoring it. This prevents a container which does not start at all from going into a restart loop.

Sine we have:

```
            "StartedAt": "2022-08-30T19:43:58.575463029Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2022-08-30T19:51:23.511624168Z"
```

then `FinishedAt - StartedAt ~ 8 seconds < 10 seconds` that's why docker engine is not restarting the container. Which I think it is not a good logic. docker engine should have a retry mechanism to retry for instance at least 3 times before giving up.

Comment: You can't put an `exec` inside a while loop (`exec` *replaces* your current process, so that statement blows away the local shell). Do you get the same error if you drop the `exec` statement?

Comment: why it did not restart is explained here: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#restart-policy-details (see first point in the list)

Comment: @Mihai you mean because container failed in less than 10 seconds. you are right. that can be the reason that it didn't restart. the main mystery is why it died with error "task already exists". I do not understand how that can happen. I should also mention that the container runs fine 99% of the time. this is a one-off issue. but I need to prevent it from happening or have a workaround for it to restart in case it happens.

Comment: one problem that I see is here: `apk update && apk add openssh-client &&`. Even a small network error can make any of the 2 fail and then eveything fails. And then the task will exit (with error, but nevertheless exit). Also the update servers can be down or slow to respond. For this reason you should move this part in a Dockerfile and build an image to reuse (or buld on `docker-compose up`). Also I'm pretty sure (have to try) that the while loop is not necessary. Only the ssh tunnel should be enough to keep it running

Comment: @Mihai the infinite while-loop is for the case when the tunnel disconnects. I think it is just faster to reconnect right away rather that restarting the container.

Comment: @larsks `exec` serves a different purpose. it is to make sure `ssh` gets PID 1 because I am using `sh`. read more [here](https://petermalmgren.com/signal-handling-docker/)

Comment: Your "purpose" in using `exec` doesn't matter. What it does is replace the current process, so putting it inside a `while` loop immediately breaks out of the while loop...and the shell script.

Comment: true, `exec` renders `while` useless but assigns PID 1 to `ssh`. I should have `ssh` and `while` in a script and `exec` that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this solution:

create `Dockerfile` in an empty folder as:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update && apk add openssh-client
```

build the image:

```bash
docker build -t alpinessh .
```

Run it with `docker run`:

```bash
docker run -d \
  --restart "always" \
  --name alpine_ssh \
  -u $(id -u):$(id -g) \
  -v $HOME/.ssh:/user/.ssh \
  -p 33333:33333 \
  alpinessh \
  ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -i /user/.ssh/${PEM_FILENAME} -nNT -L :33333:localhost:5001 abc@${IP}
```

(make sure to set the env variables that you need)

Running with docker-compose follows the same logic.

** NOTE **

Mapping `~/.ssh` inside the container is not the best of ideas. It would be better to copy the key to a different location and use it from there. Reason is: inside the container you are root and any files created in your ~/.ssh by the container would be created/accessed by root (uid=0). For example `known_hosts` - if you don't already have one, you will get a fresh new one owned by root.

For this reason I am running the container as the current UID:GID on the host.

Comment: I think your point on `apk update && apk add openssh-client` is very valid. That might have caused the premature exit issue.